# file get contents preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents

I am trying to find the correct string for preg_match in this situation

this is the data I am trying to scrape

```
  <td style="background-color:#FFFF66;font-weight:bold;">08/21/2013</td><td>
```

I just need the    08/21/2013
  If I just print $file_string it prints the whole page fine its just when I try to pull out that date.   I have a feeling it has to do with the quotes or slashes I have tried this and several other combos nogo

```
 preg_match("/bold;\">(.+)\<\/td><td>/i", $file_string, $matches);
$print = "$matches[1]";
 echo $print;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
preg_match("/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/", $file_string, $matches);
```

Comment: Use \d instead [0-9] `#\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}#`

Comment: thanks guys  I tried both of those and while reading them they make perfect sense neither return any results

Comment: this is what I had to end up using `code` preg_match("/((\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}))/", $file_string, $matches); `code`

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are greedy by default; they match as much as possible. You can use a *reluctant modifier* to match only as little as possible. Also, you don't need a backslash before a `<`.

```
preg_match("/bold;\">(.+?)<\/td><td>/i", $file_string, $matches);
```

Comment: "didn't work" usually does not provide enough information to solve any problem :)

Comment: When I said it didn't work I meant when I tested using the code you supplied above no results were displayed on the screen. With tinkering I was able to get it to work with preg_match("/((\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}))/", $file_string, $matches); not that there isnt probably several other ways to get it working. Again thank you for taking the time to submit a answer and sorry for being vague in my response.

Comment: Then you should know that I actually tested the regex before posting it and that it does "work" at least for the input given as an example; `*` and `+` being greedy often leads to surprising results and you should know how to make them non-greedy... but I agree, if what you are trying to match is dates in the shown format it's better to match the format directly like in Cyares's answer rather than text around it.